# Email finder regex with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

I have this regex for matching email addresses in a string.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})
```

It is not the best regex in the world but good enought for my use.

When I am using this with javascript like that:

```
var emails = string.match("[a-zA-Z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})");
```

I am matching only the first email address, which is normal because I am not using the g modifier.

The problem is that when I am using the g modifier like that:

```
var emails = email[0].match("[a-zA-Z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})g");
```

the var emails is null, so my match is not working.

If you can please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: please provide a real example to test on i did not get the g part well

Comment: may be duplicate of [How to use a regular expression to validate an email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :

```
var emails = yourString.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
```

Comment: Thank you Sudhir, your example works wery well. I have try it.

Comment: hi can you provide a link to learn regexp and a tool to facilate it and is javascript regexp same as java match method as syntax i mean please answer me :)

Comment: Well, you can learn regexs refering to this site:: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ , i dont know Java, but the pattern should be the same only functions using those patterns vary on different languages..

Answer (score 1):

try this i used it in servlet validation filter in my system i dont know if it works in javascript

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._]{3,}$"
```